# Instantiating an AVAudioRecorder fails

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to instantiate an AVAudioRecorder like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
NSError* error = nil;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&error];
```

But it seems I'm getting a `kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError` in the error and therefore fail to instantiate.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the format to `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` solved this issue:

`[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];`